# How can I do a cartoon-like cannon firing animation?

Tags: animation

I am working on the cannon below:

[image: The cannon in the 3D Viewport]

It is going to be used in a Christmas mobile game and is going to shoot presents. I want to make it have an animation where, when I shoot the present, it's a kind of cartoon-like animation where the present goes through it visibly. It's hard to explain, so I did a little visual explanation:

[image: Cannon before firing]

[image: canon with bulge near back]

[image: bulge is now farther forward]

[image: bulge is at the mouth and cannon ball is visible exiting mouth]

What is this kind of animation called, and what are the tools to do it?

Comment: The technique that's describe in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/243376/42221) is called exaggeration. [12 Principles of Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDqjIdI4bF4) is probably the best beginner's overview of cartoon animation available, by the way.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use a *Lattice* modifier:

Create a lattice, scale it in *Object* mode, subdivide it a bit:

[image]

Give your cylinder a *Lattice* modifier with the lattice as *Object*, select the lattice, switch to *Edit* mode, edit the lattice so that it deforms the cylinder:

[image]

Animate the lattice obect:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!